# Concatenate and compare two columns with column from other table in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have been given a badly designed database. The keys which are of format like "1.03.3" are glued to the description of the table T1, something like "1.03.3 Prices for computers".

I am building a separate table T2 where the key, "1.03.3" is separated in a column from the description "Prices for computers".

I want to build a query that will compare the appropriate value from T1 to a both fields from T2 glued, so something like:

```
T1.field1 = concat(T2.key + ' ' + T2.description)
```

and if match is found, the complete row from T2 is inserted to another table T3.

I am not sure how to do it in TSQL in SQL Server 2008.
Can somebody give an example of comparing two glued columns to a column from another table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `concat()` and `+` is redundant, so:

```
T1.field1 =  (T2.key + ' ' + T2.description)
```

`concat()` is not available in SQL Server 2008 anyway.

The complete query looks something like:

```
select t2.*
into t3
from t2 join
     t1
     on t1.field1 =  (t1.key + ' ' + t2.description);
```

If `t3` already exists, use `insert` instead of `select into`.

Comment: And inserting the match to another table T3?